# How to change class of a single child element with jquery

Tags: jquery, addclass

I am trying to do this:

```
$(".expand")[0].children[0].addClass("test");
```

It doesn't work.

This

```
$(".expand").get(0).children[0];
```

returns:

```
<i class=​"fa fa-chevron-circle-down">​::before​</i>​
```

I want to change its class. How to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per selector it looks like you are trying to add class to first child element in first element with class expand. you can use:

```
$(".expand:first > *:first").addClass("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why your attempts are not working:

1. In the first one you have converted a jquery object to dom element and you are trying to apply a jquery `.addClass()` method. so this causes as an error.
2. In the second one you have used `.get(0)` which also gives you the dom node instead of jquery object. so that also causes in error.

---

Solutions:

```
$(".expand:eq(0) > *:eq(0)").addClass("newClass");
```

this line would get you the first element of class `expand` and it will find the first child and then it applies a new class.

Although you can do this with plain js too:

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('expand')[0];
    parent.children[0].className = "newClass";
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question you are trying to add class to first element of class expand.Why don't you use :first-child selector for this purpose
$(".expand" tag:first-child)